# Admin is unable to view or assign roles in wso2 carbon

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2

I have a 3-node all-in-one API Manager instance cluster. I have configured it with ReadOnlyLDAPUserStore with the connection string, password, etc.
I can see all the users in the domain when I list the users in the carbon page. However, as admin, I am unable to view roles or make changes. Practically anything I click throws a WSO2 Carbon error: "Error while loading roles of . Error: Error occurred while accessing Java Security Manager Privilege Block"

Also, I now tried to login with my own AD credentials but it fails to authenticate. What am I missing?

Logs around that operation:

```
TID: [-1234] [] [2019-03-18 19:00:42,899] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.authorization.JDBCAuthorizationManager} -  Authorization cache miss for username : admin resource /permission/admin/manage/identity/rolemgt/view action : ui.execute {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.authorization.JDBCAuthorizationManager}
TID: [-1234] [] [2019-03-18 19:00:42,899] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.authorization.JDBCAuthorizationManager} -  Allowed roles for the ResourceID: /permission/admin/manage/identity/rolemgt/view Action: ui.execute {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.authorization.JDBCAuthorizationManager}
TID: [-1234] [] [2019-03-18 19:00:42,899] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.authorization.JDBCAuthorizationManager} -  role: admin {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.authorization.JDBCAuthorizationManager}
TID: [-1234] [] [2019-03-18 19:00:42,899] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.authorization.JDBCAuthorizationManager} -  Roles which have permission for resource : /permission/admin/manage/identity/rolemgt/view action : ui.execute {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.authorization.JDBCAuthorizationManager}
TID: [-1234] [] [2019-03-18 19:00:42,899] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.authorization.JDBCAuthorizationManager} -  Role :  admin {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.authorization.JDBCAuthorizationManager}
TID: [-1234] [] [2019-03-18 19:00:42,899] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.authorization.JDBCAuthorizationManager} -  admin user has permitted resource :  /permission/admin/manage/identity/rolemgt/view, action :ui.execute {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.authorization.JDBCAuthorizationManager}
TID: [-1234] [] [2019-03-18 19:00:42,901] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.AbstractUserStoreManager} -  Error occurred while accessing Java Security Manager Privilege Block {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.AbstractUserStoreManager}
TID: [-1234] [] [2019-03-18 19:00:42,901] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.user.mgt.UserRealmProxy} -  org.wso2.carbon.user.core.UserStoreException: Error occurred while accessing Java Security Manager Privilege Block {org.wso2.carbon.user.mgt.UserRealmProxy}
TID: [-1234] [] [2019-03-18 19:00:42,906] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.user.mgt.ui.UserAdminClient} -  Error occurred while accessing Java Security Manager Privilege Block {org.wso2.carbon.user.mgt.ui.UserAdminClient}
org.wso2.carbon.user.mgt.stub.UserAdminUserAdminException: UserAdminUserAdminException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.mgt.stub.UserAdminStub.getRolesOfUser(UserAdminStub.java:2555)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.mgt.ui.UserAdminClient.getRolesOfUser(UserAdminClient.java:154)
    at org.apache.jsp.user.view_002droles_jsp._jspService(view_002droles_jsp.java:274)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:439)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:395)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:339)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    at org.wso2.carbon.ui.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:155)
    at org.wso2.carbon.ui.TilesJspServlet.service(TilesJspServlet.java:80)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.helper.ContextPathServletAdaptor.service(ContextPathServletAdaptor.java:37)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ServletRegistration.service(ServletRegistration.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.processAlias(ProxyServlet.java:128)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.service(ProxyServlet.java:68)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.servlet.DelegationServlet.service(DelegationServlet.java:68)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:743)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:603)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:542)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.RequestDispatcherAdaptor.include(RequestDispatcherAdaptor.java:37)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.helper.ContextPathServletAdaptor$RequestDispatcherAdaptor.include(ContextPathServletAdaptor.java:369)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspRuntimeLibrary.include(JspRuntimeLibrary.java:905)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doInclude(PageContextImpl.java:688)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.include(PageContextImpl.java:682)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor93.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tiles.jsp.context.JspUtil.doInclude(JspUtil.java:87)
    at org.apache.tiles.jsp.context.JspTilesRequestContext.include(JspTilesRequestContext.java:88)
    at org.apache.tiles.jsp.context.JspTilesRequestContext.dispatch(JspTilesRequestContext.java:82)
    at org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:465)
    at org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.InsertAttributeTag.render(InsertAttributeTag.java:140)
    at org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.InsertAttributeTag.render(InsertAttributeTag.java:117)
    at org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.RenderTagSupport.execute(RenderTagSupport.java:171)
    at org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.RoleSecurityTagSupport.doEndTag(RoleSecurityTagSupport.java:75)
    at org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.ContainerTagSupport.doEndTag(ContainerTagSupport.java:80)
    at org.apache.jsp.admin.layout.template_jsp._jspx_meth_tiles_005finsertAttribute_005f7(template_jsp.java:737)
    at org.apache.jsp.admin.layout.template_jsp._jspService(template_jsp.java:400)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:439)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:395)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:339)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    at org.wso2.carbon.ui.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:155)
    at org.wso2.carbon.ui.TilesJspServlet.service(TilesJspServlet.java:80)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.helper.ContextPathServletAdaptor.service(ContextPathServletAdaptor.java:37)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ServletRegistration.service(ServletRegistration.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.processAlias(ProxyServlet.java:128)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.service(ProxyServlet.java:68)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.servlet.DelegationServlet.service(DelegationServlet.java:68)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:743)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:485)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:410)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:337)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.RequestDispatcherAdaptor.forward(RequestDispatcherAdaptor.java:30)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.helper.ContextPathServletAdaptor$RequestDispatcherAdaptor.forward(ContextPathServletAdaptor.java:362)
    at org.apache.tiles.servlet.context.ServletTilesRequestContext.forward(ServletTilesRequestContext.java:198)
    at org.apache.tiles.servlet.context.ServletTilesRequestContext.dispatch(ServletTilesRequestContext.java:185)
    at org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:419)
    at org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:370)
    at org.wso2.carbon.ui.action.ActionHelper.render(ActionHelper.java:52)
    at org.wso2.carbon.ui.TilesJspServlet.service(TilesJspServlet.java:101)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.helper.ContextPathServletAdaptor.service(ContextPathServletAdaptor.java:37)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ServletRegistration.service(ServletRegistration.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.processAlias(ProxyServlet.java:128)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.service(ProxyServlet.java:68)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.servlet.DelegationServlet.service(DelegationServlet.java:68)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.wso2.carbon.ui.filters.cache.URLBasedCachePreventionFilter.doFilter(URLBasedCachePreventionFilter.java:57)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.owasp.csrfguard.CsrfGuardFilter.doFilter(CsrfGuardFilter.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.filter.CharacterSetFilter.doFilter(CharacterSetFilter.java:65)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.doFilter(HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.java:124)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:110)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.context.rewrite.valve.TenantContextRewriteValve.invoke(TenantContextRewriteValve.java:80)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.authz.valve.AuthorizationValve.invoke(AuthorizationValve.java:91)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.auth.valve.AuthenticationValve.invoke(AuthenticationValve.java:65)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.continueInvocation(CompositeValve.java:99)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonTomcatValve$1.invoke(CarbonTomcatValve.java:47)
    at org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.TenantLazyLoaderValve.invoke(TenantLazyLoaderValve.java:57)
    at org.wso2.carbon.event.receiver.core.internal.tenantmgt.TenantLazyLoaderValve.invoke(TenantLazyLoaderValve.java:48)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.TomcatValveContainer.invokeValves(TomcatValveContainer.java:47)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValve.java:62)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:159)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:962)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:57)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:445)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1115)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:637)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1775)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1734)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
TID: [-1] [] [2019-03-18 19:04:57,199]  INFO {org.wso2.andes.kernel.disruptor.inbound.InboundDBSyncRequestEvent} -  Running DB sync task. {org.wso2.andes.kernel.disruptor.inbound.InboundDBSyncRequestEvent}
TID: [-1] [] [2019-03-18 19:04:57,217]  WARN {org.wso2.andes.kernel.subscription.AndesSubscriptionManager} -  Subscriptions are not in sync. Local Subscription available in subscription registry of node NODE:localhost/127.0.0.1 but not in DB. Thus adding to DB subscription=subscriptionId=f7ccaf10-0ad8-485f-9ae3-c7617e1f20cd,storageQueue=AMQP_Topic_throttledata_NODE:localhost/127.0.0.1,protocolType=AMQP,isActive=true,connection= [ connectedIP=/10.128.138.4:44872/1,connectedNode=NODE:localhost/127.0.0.1,protocolChannelID=2bd6f019-f813-4a77-8516-8ddfce3db456 ] {org.wso2.andes.kernel.subscription.AndesSubscriptionManager}
```

Comment: As of now there still is no clear solution or root cause to this problem. This maybe an issue in wso2am 2.6.0 (vanilla version). WSO2 team is working on shipping a log patch to understand the problem in more detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was an issue with a base apim 2.6.0. Thereafter, updating using `wum update` provided some fixes that resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The `GroupSearchBase` value must be incorrectly set. Please verify that.

Comment: GroupSearchBase is set correctly. I was able to search groups and add users but when I lookup users and try to see their permissions, roles, etc I see the popup error like I mentioned.
The AD groups and users are populated in WSO2 Carbon when I list Users and Roles so it is not an issue with that setting.